# What is correct "Your father just told me" or "Your father has just told me."

Tags: american-english, present-perfect, past-simple

In Oscar a 1991 American slapstick crime comedy film directed by John Landis, I heard: "Your father just told me".

Why do not correct to say "Your father has just told me."?

Because in "How English Works" page 172, 16:

> They (just discover) a new fuel - it's half the price of petrol and much cleaner.

The correct answer is by the book:

> They **have just discovered** a new fuel - it's half the price of petrol and much cleaner.

Is there any connection with the fact that the book "How English Works" is by Oxford University Press UK, but the movie is by Hollywood in the USA?

Comment: Why do you think that it is not correct? Both are perfectly good.

Comment: @ColinFine if so why in authors of the book did not give both possibilities correct?

Comment: Because authors of books like that often have Opinions.

Comment: There is an element of British vs US English: when I was growing up, the simple past with "just" was must less common in British English than US English. To my (British) ears "I just saw him" or "I just did it" sounded strange and American. But in this particular respect the two varieties have moved closer in the last sixty years, and both forms are used in BrEng (as I believe they always were in USEng).

Answer (score 2):

If something **has just happened** it means that it happened in that exact moment, with that being said, if the phrase is **"Your father has just told me"** it would mean that it happened a second before the speaker learned about that "something" he's talking about.

**Your father just told me that** would mean that the speaker learned about it a few minutes earlier **not precisely at that exact same moment**. 
The difference is really subtle. I struggle with this myself sometimes, but that's the difference. if something **has** just happened then it happened at that exact moment. **It indicates a more immediate past.**

Comment: To be more precise, "just told me" *can* include just this moment, and also slightly longer ago. "Has just told me" more strongly implies immediacy. Then there's "just **now** told me", which also indicates immediacy. English is full of little wrinkles, isn't it?

Comment: I hear weird sentences like that all day. Today I heard "**As least as possible**" from some Joe Schmoe who walked into my job looking for the least expensive product for sale. Saying "**Job**" for your workplace is just another one of those things.

Comment: To walk into a job, in my experience, means to get a job without effort...

Comment: Not in Boston apparently. A job is a physical place.

Comment: You write that *Just happened* implies that something occurred at *that exact moment." But *what* exact moment are you talking about? In any vase, *just happened* does not necessarily describe an exact moment. E.g., *Soldiers had just returned from the war and began having families* does not discuss an *exact moment.*

Comment: It is not true that *has just* necessarily describes *a second before* [the moment of speaking]. A: *It's raining.* B: *Oh no. And of course I've just washed the car.* It's quite unlikely the act occurred a second before B spoke.

Answer (score 0):

I found in a book strongly this rule: The difference between the Britain English and the American
English is:
he has just told = Britain English
he just told = American English.

Comment: Here is the excelent explanation of that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmGfX1Jm2Fs

Answer (score -3):

While the correct construction requires **has just told me**, native English speakers frequently omit the **has** from such sentences.

Whether the present perfect tense or the past tense is used, the meaning is identical.

So you will hear people say things like:

> he just left
>   he just walked past
>   he just threw it away

Such omissions, generally found in the spoken language and informal writing, are common shortcuts. It's just the way people speak.

**Has just told me** and **just told me** mean exactly the same thing, whether they refer  to a statement that was made a minute, an hour or a day ago.